# CPU utilization in performance testing

Tags: performance-testing

I am doing performance testing on an app. I found when the number of virtual users increases, the response time increases linearly(should be natural, right?), but the CPU utilization stops increasing when reaches around 60%. Does it mean the CPU is the bottleneck? If not, what could be the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck might or might not be CPU, you need to consider monitoring other OS metrics as well, to wit:

- Physical RAM
- Swap usage
- Network IO
- Disk IO

Each of them could be the bottleneck.

Also when you increase number of users **ideal** system should increase the number of TPS ([transactions per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactions_per_second)) by the same factor. When you increase virtual users and TPS is not getting increased the situation is called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and you need to find out what is slowing your system down.

If resources utilization is far from 95-100% and your system provides large response times the reason can be non-optimal code of your application or slow database query or something like that, in this case you will need to use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to get to the bottom of the issue.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information on the application under test monitoring concept